# Remember login with PhoneGap and Laravel

Tags: php, cordova, laravel, remember-me

I need to be permanently connected in a PhoneGap Application with Laravel.

In a webpage, I can use the remember me option but in the PhoneGap Application I must save the token in **localStorage** and send it via AJAX in each request. In each request i must respond with a new token, for security.

**I know that Laravel generate a new token in each login/logout action**. It's ok, but I want to know if there is something to execute the login with the remember token and after, regenerate it.

Comment: You could write your own authentication system for this in Laravel. The first time requires the username/password, which is passed from the phone app to Laravel, which responds with a token of your own choosing. The token is used to auth each time, using your own auth system in Laravel. You could rotate tokens as well, for extra security.

Answer (score 0):

Some insight to the code, where the Session update is happening after a login can be seen in docs
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php#L415

```
public function login(UserInterface $user, $remember = false)
{
    $this->updateSession($user->getAuthIdentifier());

    // code missing
}


protected function updateSession($id)
{
    $this->session->put($this->getName(), $id);

    $this->session->migrate(true);
}
```